# vuejs when refresh data from vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Good evening, sir,

I have a blind with vuex, and I get data from Laravel in Json.
For example, to receive data from the logged-in user, I make a request with his token, which sends me his data, which is stored in the blind.

I have the choice between making this request when the page loads, or each time I change the component.
Except that I have the impression that to do it with each change of component would consume a lot. But to do it when the page refreshes would not give me reliable data.

There is my actions from store :

```html
const actions = {
    setUsers: async (context) => {
        let uri = '/api/auth/me'
        let token = getters.getToken(state);
        const response = await axios.post(uri, token);
        context.commit('setUsers', response.data)
    },
}
```

What do you think about that? Do you have another solution?

Kylian

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "Changing the component" is triggering the action from within the component, that doesn't take so much effort to do, because your component is already rendered, you're just comiting a mutation to update the state. While refreshing the page would definitely heavier because you're reloading your entire application.